# Windows 10 setup skipped partition D

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I've recently upgraded to Windows 10 but for some reason the setup didn't set up system partition D. During the setup, I created 3 partitions but I now have partitions C, E and F.

However, if I plug in my USB memory stick, it is always assigned to partition D.

Is there any way I can swap partition D with partition F?

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAZGv.png)

Comment: Use Computer Management - Disk Management, and swap the drive letter around. Just make sure you didn't have any programs installed / dependent on a particular drive letter.

Comment: I guess you would have used USB drive to install the OS, So the USB drive will be assigned to D this will be the cause. Open run and type diskmgmt.msc and change the drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Computer` in `Windows Explorer`
2. On `Computer` click `Manage`
3. In left panel choose `Disk Managment`

there you can see your disks and partitions on these disks. You can remap letters of these partitions.

4. Click right on partition you want to change letter
5. Chose `Change drive letter...`

[image: Disk managment tool]

6. Select assigned letter and press `Change...` button

or

6. if no letter assigned, press `add...`
7. Choose new letter

[image: Changing assigned drive letter]

8. Ok and Ok ...

// I am using Windows in Czech language, please edit post by exact label texts.